# Durandel + Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I worked with two jquery libraries in MVC 4 project which worked fine.
Now i building the same web site using MVC 5 + web api + durandel and knockout. 
But i dont know how to insert those libraries:
http://www.3quarks.com/en/SegmentDisplay/
http://brandonlwhite.github.io/sevenSeg.js/

I want to insert them in a table ( foreach)
the JS is in require as define module
and not in the HTML file,
i dont know how to start and need help please.

Comment: If you read the doc in the link you provided, you would have noticed SevenSeg provide a binding for Knockout.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, include the following libraries :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="sevenSeg.js"></script>
```

Either directly in your index.html file, or via the `RegisterBundles` method in file in your App_Start folder :

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(
        new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/vendor")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/knockout-3.3.0.debug.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/sevenSeg.js")
    );
}
```

Then include it in your index file :

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/vendor")
```

Then you should be able to use the SevenSeg data binding like this :

```
<div data-bind="sevenSeg: {digits: 5, value: testValue1}"></div>
```

If the data binding does not work, you would have to create a custom binding handler in an external file (eg `/Scripts/sevenSegCustom.js` and load your custom binding in your main.js file like this :

```
define(['sevenSegCustom'], function(sevenSegCustom) {
  composition.addBindingHandler('myCustomSSBinding', sevenSegCustom.sevenSegCustom)
}
```

Then use it like this :

```
<div data-bind="myCustomSSBinding: {digits: 5, value: testValue1}"></div>
```

Hope it helps !